Is wifi and bluetooth not support in ubuntu
My Asus laptop has mideatek mt7902 network manager and model is X1504ZA-NJ325WS in this Ubuntu wifi and blutooth not supported how to resolve this ?

Sorry but that wifi/bluetooth combo is not supported in any Linux distribution at thi time
